# Limit of nth root of 1/n as n goes to infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I was wondering if you could assist me with the attached picture.

[Limit of nth root of 1/n as n goes to infinity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaeE2.png)

I know the value of this limit is 1, so why am I getting 0 after I bring the limit under the nth root? The nth root is continuous at 0, so I don't understand the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot let $n\to\infty$ only in one part of the expression. That is, you cannot insert the limit under the $n$'th root sign, while keeping the $n$'th root sign.

Comment: A thumb rule: never write $\lim a_n =b_n$. The limit of  sequence $\{a_n\}$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: I thought it might be something to do with that. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 3):

You have 
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}} = \exp \left( -\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)$$

Now when $n$ tends to $+\infty$, $-\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ tends to $0$.

so you deduce that $\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}$ tends to $\exp(0)=1$.